# Creating a PHP Calendar

Tags: php, calendar

I am trying to create a calendar to show the events to be held or already held. I'm planning on a full screen calendar so that the events can be shown right beside the date . Can some one tell me how to get the dates under the correct column and row .

I dont want to use any ready made libraries. I want to create a calender from scratch . I am not able to understand how to get the dates into their respective slots in a calendar table.

Comment: Too little information to answer this - ask a specific question and provide us with detailed information about your setup.

Comment: I dont want to use any ready made libraries. I want to create a calender from scratch . I am not able to understand how to get the dates into their respective slots in a calendar table.

Comment: This is a very generic description of your problem, not an actual specific question. Please see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/ and try googling on how to ask productive questions that we will *love* to answer.

Comment: It helps if you include code showing people what you are trying to do or how it's being applied. Otherwise it sounds like you want someone to write it for you.

Answer (score 2):

1) Get rows from database, ordered by date

2) Pick what date to start with

3) Pick the date you want to end with

4) For each day between start and end, check the data from the database for a record and output if it exists on that date.

*Hint:* you can use `getdate($timestamp);` to get an array containing the separated date info about your timestamp. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php)

There are a number of ways to do this, depending on framework, desired functionality, desired layout, etc.

Comment: I dont need how to get the data from database and display. I want how to get the correct date into the correct slot in a calendar table.

Comment: How are you tracking dates in the database? Timestamp? DateTime? Date? Varchar? Int?

Comment: @PradyumnaSharma : See the hint in my revised answer.